# How to share models between 2 or more sails projects

Tags: sails.js

I have two sails projects, a website - the frontend and a administration backend. The projects should be separate but they share the api/models folder. What is the preferred way to share them?
At the moment we used a a separate git repository which we clone into api/models (A git submodule would also work). I am asking myself if this is the best way or the recommended way to do so?

Does sails v0.11 with the sails hook https://github.com/node-machine/sails-hook-machines solve that in a better more modular way?

Thanks so far

Answer (score 3):

First of all:

> If both applications work on the one server you can symlink model folder from one application to the other.

Please do not do this. This is devops hackery at its worst, and is a great way to make your project un-deployable.

Now, for a solution:

In my [sails-auth](https://github.com/tjwebb/sails-auth) module, I use the standard sails generator and create extensible model stubs in `api/models`.  For example, here I generate `User` and `Passport` models: https://github.com/tjwebb/sails-auth/blob/master/index.js#L5-L6.

Another example also is here: https://github.com/tjwebb/sails-permissions/blob/master/index.js#L5-L8.

The actual stubs look like this: https://github.com/tjwebb/sails-permissions/blob/master/api/models/User.js#L1-L5

sails.js unfortunately doesn't have a convention for doing this; but the above approach has worked well in practice for my projects.

Answer (score 0):

If both applications work on the one server you can symlink model folder from one application to the other.

If not (or you have differences in models or some other reason) git submodules is definite way to go. `sails-hook-machines` is unstable at the moment, think twice if you want to have it in your production.

Comment: We tried symlinks. It works only if you do not have any dependencies/require calls in your models. If you have for instance a 'require("lodash")', node will make a realpath and will search the dependency lodash in the models directory. In that case you might think to add the dependencies to the models directory with a separate package.json. But that won`t work because sails makes include-all which would try to load every js file from node_modules dir.

Comment: @ThomasFritz This is the problem I didn't think about while posting my answer. If your dependencies is common stuff (like async or lodash) you can put it to `globals` config and let sails to require them under the hood. Otherwise, it seems like I have not solution of your problem. By myself I have one sails instance both for admins and users. My user model has accessLevel attribute, and I delegate code flow with several policies. This is useful because I can use common methods both for different group of users. Administrator panel has it own view base layout, as well. Maybe, this helps you